# Yield calculation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to calculate the Yield based on Wordpress meta_values and I'm using the MySQL statement below, which is not working. The SUM(returned.meta_value+staked.meta_value)-SUM(staked.meta_value))/SUM(staked.meta_value))*100) doesn't return any values.

Can someone help me with what's wrong with the expression below.

Thank you.

```
global $post;
$post_author = $post->post_author;
$post_status = 'publish';
$yield = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    SELECT (ROUND((((SUM(returned.meta_value+staked.meta_value)-SUM(staked.meta_value))/SUM(staked.meta_value))*100),2),2)
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
    JOIN {$wpdb->users} u ON p.post_author = u.ID
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} staked
        ON p.ID = staked.post_id AND staked.meta_key = 'staked'
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} returned 
        ON p.ID = returned.post_id AND returned.meta_key = 'returned'
    WHERE p.post_author = %s AND p.post_status = %s
    ",
    $post_author, $post_status
    ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't make sense.  The `select` statement is using the aliases `balance` and `bet`.  The `from` clause has the aliases `pm` and `posts`.

Do you mean this?

```
SELECT (ROUND((((SUM(pm.meta_value+pm.meta_value)-SUM(pm.meta_value))/SUM(pm.meta_value))*100),2),2)
FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm INNER JOIN
     {$wpdb->posts} p
     ON pm.post_id = p.ID
WHERE pm.meta_key = %s AND pm.meta_key1 = %s AND p.post_author = %s AND
      Month(p.post_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) AND p.post_status = %s
```

Comment: ok, should I keep using aliases in the select statement and change the from or vice-versa. returned and staked are the meta_keys and I want to return their values to calculate the yield. Can you help, please.

Comment: @qebas . . . use aliases in the `select` statement, just change them to the correct aliases.

Comment: I tried with the statement above and it still doesn't work, no values returned.

Comment: @qebas . . . I missed one of the aliases in the `select` statement.

Comment: If I have pm.meta_value+pm.meta_value in the select statement how will it know which one is retuned and which one is staked?